# Are [ɚ] and [ər] interchangeable for (儿化) er-hua?

Tags: writing

I've got different resources doing different things for er-hua, e.g.:

**包儿**

resource material #1

> [pər]

resource material #2

> [pɚ]

is [ɚ] and [ər] interchangeable for (儿化) er-hua?

I would hazard to guess that [ər] is just a lazy [ɚ].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They should be the same. It is just differences in notation. [ər] is commonly used by Sinologists, while [ɚ] is actual IPA.

In the Beijing dialect (and standard Mandarin), 包儿 should be pronounced as something like [paʊɻ] (probably written by Sinologists as [paur]). It looks like you're looking at something like Sichuanese, where 包儿 is pronounced as [pɚ].

Take a look at the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erhua) on erhua for more details.

Comment: What is the term of this commonly used notation by Sinologists?

Comment: @user3306356 It's just a modified version of IPA used by many Chinese scholars. Books using this type of notation would just call this IPA (broad transcription).

Answer (score 0):

NO, [ɚ][ər] are interchangeable in the case of (儿化) er-hua because 儿 comes first. In other case, when 儿 comes last, then they are interchangeable, for instance, 包儿，花儿。

Answer (score -1):

The first:
[ɚ]=[ər]=[ə^ɹ(as e^x )] [ər] for print convenience.
The second:
包儿 is [paur]